# Copy permissions from another table

Tags: postgresql, database-permissions

Is it possible to copy the user permissions from one table in a PostgreSQL database to another table? Is it just a matter of updating the `pg_class.relacl` column value for the target table to the value for the source table, as in:

```
UPDATE pg_class
SET relacl=(SELECT relacl FROM pg_class WHERE relname='source_table')
WHERE relname='target_table';
```

This seems to work, but am I missing anything else that may need to be done or other 'gotchas' with this method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can use command-line instead of SQL then a safer approach would be to use pg_dump:

```
pg_dump dbname -t oldtablename -s \
| egrep '^(GRANT|REVOKE)' \
| sed 's/oldtablename/newtablename/' \
| psql dbname
```

I assume a unix server. On Windows I'd use `pg_dump -s` to a file, manually edit it and then import it to a database.

Maybe you'll also need to copy permissions to sequences owned by this table - pg_dump will work.

Answer (score 3):

The `pg_dump` approach is nice and simple, however, it doesn't work with tables in other schemas, as the output doesn't qualify the table with schema name. Instead it generates:

```
SET search_path = foo, pg_catalog;
...
GRANT SELECT ON foo_table to foo_user;
```

and will fail to grant privileges to an nonexistent `public.foo_table` relation.

Also, if you have relations with the same name in different schemas, you need to ensure that you only rename the table in the specified schema. I began to hack a bash script base on the above to take care of this but it started to become a bit unwieldy, so I switched to perl.

Usage: `transfer-acl old-qualified-relation=new-qualified-relation`

e.g. `transfer-acl foo.foo_table=foo.bar_table` will apply the grants on `foo.foo_table` to the `foo.bar_table`. I didn't implement any `REVOKE` rewriting because I wasn't able to get a dump to emit any.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %rename = map {(split '=')} @ARGV;

open my $dump, '-|', qw(pg_dump customer -s), map {('-t', $_)} keys %rename
    or die "Cannot open pipe from pg_dump: $!\n";

my $schema = 'public';
while (<$dump>) {
    if (/^SET search_path = (\w+)/) {
        $schema = $1;
    }
    elsif (/^(GRANT .*? ON TABLE )(\w+)( TO (?:[^;]+);)$/) {
        my $fq_table = "$schema." . $2; # fully-qualified schema.table
        print "$1$rename{$fq_table}$3\n" if exists $rename{$fq_table};
    }
}
```

Pipe the results of this to `psql` and you're set.