# Can you copy table privileges from one table to another in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, privileges

I've got a import process that copies a table schema with the code below and then populates the table with data. However it doesn't copy over the roles granted.

```
CREATE TABLE TOTABLE (LIKE FROMTABLE INCLUDING INDEXES)
```

Is there a way I can copy privileges when the schema is copied, or I can apply the privileges afterwards from the "FROMTABLE"?

Comment: In general, if you want this you should be creating a role, assigning the desired rights to the role, then just granting rights to that role to the new table.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL copy permissions from another table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822798/postgresql-copy-permissions-from-another-table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Information about tables in postgresql are stored in the `pg_class` table.  The field containing table privileges is `relacl`.

So something like the following would work:

`update pg_class set relacl = (select relacl from pg_class where relname = 'from_table') where relname='to_table';`

Note that `pg_class` has metadata for all tables -- so you should also take care to make sure you are using the right schema (`relnamespace`) in case there are tables of the same name in multiple schemas.

Answer (score 9):

Be ***very careful*** when manipulating catalog tables directly. It's generally advisable to use DDL statements exclusively. Catalog tables are not meant to be written by users. If you mess this up, your DB cluster might be corrupted beyond repair. You have been warned.

**Update**: Turns out, the above warning is quite right. This was a bad idea to begin with. Standard `GRANT` / `REVOKE` commands (as well as the [default privilege system](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html)) also make entries in [`pg_shdepend`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-shdepend.html) table to remember dependencies between objects and roles mentioned in the access control list (except for the owner, which is linked anyway). [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-shdepend.html)

> The catalog `pg_shdepend` records the dependency relationships between
> database objects and shared objects, such as roles. This information
> allows PostgreSQL to ensure that those objects are unreferenced before
> attempting to delete them.

By manipulating the access control list (`relacl` for relations) directly, dependencies fall out of sync, which can lead to "strange" problems when trying to drop roles later.

There was a recent [discussion about "Copying Permissions" on pgsql-hackers](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CADkLM%3DdovdTM4LJ1-_YuNJWjeOU00XrwYvhU5v3-ZytBZ8zDbQ%40mail.gmail.com#CADkLM=dovdTM4LJ1-_YuNJWjeOU00XrwYvhU5v3-ZytBZ8zDbQ@mail.gmail.com) (Nov 2016), but nothing has been implemented, yet.

#### Incomplete solution (do not use!)

The [query presented by @Robert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27302555/939860) has a bug (as he noted): `relname` is *not* unique. There can be any number of tables with the same name in multiple schemas of the same db. To fix:

```sql
UPDATE pg_class c_to
SET    relacl = c_from.relacl 
FROM   pg_class c_from
WHERE  c_from.oid  = 'public.from_table'::regclass
AND    c_to.oid    = 'public.to_table'::regclass
```

#### Differences

- The cast to `regclass` picks a table deterministically, *even without schema-qualification*. Details:
- [How do I speed up counting rows in a PostgreSQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570488/how-do-i-speed-up-counting-rows-in-a-postgresql-table/14571935#14571935)
- If one of the tables is not found, you get an exception immediately (the cast to `regclass` fails).
  @Robert's query would happily set `relacl` to NULL if `from_table` is not found.

Answer (score 0):

A table DDL and its permissions can be dumped to a file using

`pg_dump --schema-only --table=my_old_table --schema=my_schema --dbname=my_db --file=my_old_table_ddl.sql ...`

Next `my_old_table_ddl.sql` can be edited to replace old_table_name by new_ table_name and
the DLL executed using `psql` command.

Executing GRANT statements only allows copying just the permissions.